# Regression with before and after

Tags: r

I have a dataset with four variables (df)

| household | group | income | post |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 20'000 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 22'000 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 10'000 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 20'000 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 20'000 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 21'000 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 9'000 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 16'000 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 8'000 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 18'000 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 22'000 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 26'000 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 12'000 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 24'000 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 | 24'000 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 27'000 | 1 |

Group is a binary variable and is 1, when household got support from state. and post variable is also binary and is 1, when it is after some household got support from state.
Now I would like to run a before vs after regression that estimates the group effect by comparing post-period and before period for the supported group. I would like to put the dependent variable in logs, to have the effect in percentage, so the impact of state support on income.

I used that code, but I don't know if it is right to get the answer?

```r
library("fixest")

feols(log(income) ~ group + post,data=df) %>% etable()
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the classic 2x2 design your code was almost correct. Change '+' with '*'. This tell us that the supported group increased the income with 7 250 more than the group which not received support.

```
comparing = feols(income ~ group * post,data)
comparing_log = feols(log(income) ~ group * post,data)
etable(comparing,comparing_log)
```

[image: 2x2 design]

PS: The interpretation of the coefficient as percentage change is a good approximation for small numbers. The correct formula for % change is: exp(beta)-1. In this case it is exp(0.5829)-1 = 0.7912.
So the change here is 79,12%.

Comment: I don't think this is right, how are you doing a before vs after comparison when you are removing the before part from the data?

Comment: I am not removing the before part. I remove group =0 which is the un-supported group. That was my interpretation of " comparing post-period and before period for the supported group."

Comment: I want to see the impact of group on income

Comment: Have now edited the answer. Is this what you are looking for?